# How to delete something in a JavaScript object that can be nested arbitrarily deep?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript object that manages all of my app's data. It looks something like this:

```
parent = {
    data: 'abcdef',
    children: {
        'child1' : {
             data: 'ghijkl',
             children: {...}
         },
         'child2' : {
             data: 'mnopqr',
             children: {...}
         }
    }
}
```

In order to manage which is the currently active node, I keep an array called 'address' that is a list of which names to follow to traverse the overall structure and reach the desired point. For example [] as address gives the whole structure, ['child1'] as address gives just the 'child1' of the main object.

My problem is that given an address, I need to be able to remove that particular node, which can be arbitrarily deep within the overall structure, how could I go about this? For example remove(['child1']) should remove 'child1' from the example structure, with 'child2' remaining intact. All remove operations should return the entire structure with the single node removed.

Comment: Maybe like this `delete parent.children['child1'];`

Comment: maybe an array for children suits better ...

Comment: @LGSon The problem is that they are nested arbitrarily deep. I may need to delete the child of the child of the child of child1. That method only works when the depth is 1. My example didn't explain this very well.

Comment: (1) Why is your address an array and not just a string (which could be null for the root and the property name for the targetted object)? (2) are all your nested property names unique, or how else do you know which one is the target? (3) If the array is supposed to give the *path* to the target, then why you have `['child1']` and not `['children', 'child1']` in your example?

Comment: so when you say arbitrarily deep, would your address look something like `[childN,childN2,childN3]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do it.

```
remove = function(address, tree) {
    if (address.length === 1) { 
        delete tree.children[address[0]]; 
    } else {
        remove(address.slice(1), tree.children[address[0]]);
    }
}
```

Pass in `parent` as the tree parameter to start with.

Comment: This assumes that your address array goes from the top to the bottom left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse if this is not what you are looking for, I 'think' I know what you are going for. But recursion might be your best bet. I just whipped this up, but perhaps someone else has a more succinct solution.

Lets assume, in the example below you want to delete "child1a",which is nested. We should be able to do that.

```
parent = {
    data: 'abcdef',
    children: {
        'child1' : {
             data: 'ghijkl',
             children: {
                'child1a' : {
                     data: 'data for child1a',
                     children: {}
                 }
             }
         },
         'child2' : {
             data: 'mnopqr',
             children: {}
         }
    }
};

function deleteNode(node, child) {
    if(node[child]) {
      delete node[child];
      return;
    }
    var children = Object.keys(node);
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {    
      return deleteNode(node[children[i]].children, child);
    }
}
deleteNode(parent.children, 'child1a')
```